# What's best for drawing a calendar - SVG or canvas?

Tags: canvas, svg

It will be a large calendar, like iCal.  I started a working prototype in plain old HTML using tables (for the calendar days etc) and divs (for the entries in the calendar), but am thinking canvas or SVG might be a better fit.

The entries in a calendar are going to be interactive - drag and drop, edit etc. so which would be best for this application?

Comment: If you'd like to see one done with canvas, check out the one I made: http://sudoit.org/projects/canvasCalendar. I put that together in one evening and it works pretty well. It doesn't do the interactive functionality you were speaking of, though if you were planning to go the HTML5 route it would be a good base.

Comment: Thanks! Wordpress changed how my routes were handled. Should be fixed in an hour or so.

Comment: https://github.com/ccallebs/HTML5-Canvas-Calendar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG is better than Canvas when you have anything more than a trivial amount of interaction with individual visual portions of the drawing: you can attach event handlers directly to SVG elements and modify properties of them to move items around. SVG is a *retained drawing mode* graphics system, meaning that (unlike canvas) after you draw the items you can change properties of individual items and have the drawing change.

Canvas is better than SVG when you need to do interesting per-pixel effects, such as blurs or explosions.